# What remedies are mentioned for a Dwija missing Trikala sandhya vandanam?

Tags: vedas, puranas, sandhyavandanam

I want to know the remedies mentioned in Vedas and Puranas for a Dwija missing Trikala Sandhyavandanam.

If possible also remedies for one missing Madhyahnika Sandhya vandanam alone.

Comment: That answers my question. Please mark this as duplicate. Thank you.

Comment: @Tej You can mark a duplicate yourself. No need of others.

Comment: Oh. Didnt know that.